# Insert large amount of recrods to database with relationships and without duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I got some records(around 30k) from a 3rd party with a structure similar to this(all strings):

`first_name, last_name, city`

Also I have 2 tables in MySQL: users and cities(around 25k records). The users table has a foreign key to the cities table.

I need to fill `users` table with the records from api and foregin key to the `citites` table. If city does not exist, I need to create it. So my code looks like this:

```php
<?php

$users = $api->getUsers();

$existingUsers = $this->userRepository->getIds();
$existingCities = $this->cityRepository->geIdsIndexedByName();

$db->beginTransaction();

foreach ($users as $i => $user) {
  // if no city with such name, then create new and insert to array
  if (!array_key_exists($user['city'], $existingCities) { 
    $cityId = $db->insert('cities', ['name' => $user['city']]);
    $existingCities[$user['city_id']] = $cityId;
  }
  $user['city_id'] = $existingCities[$user['city']];

  if (in_array($user['id'], $existingUsers) { // if record with such id exists, then we update it
      $db->update('users', $user);
  } else {
      $db->insert('users', $user);
  }
  if (($i % 100) === 0) { // use transactions to avoid mass inserts and updates
    $db->commit();
    $db->beginTransaction();
  }
}
```

What I don't like, is that I have to load all cities and all users into memory to check if records already exist. I don't use ORM here, no object, only tiny arrays, but it still eats resources and I would like to reduce memory consumption. Are there any practices to optimize that process?

I have an idea to use NoSQL storage as a cache for existing users and citites, but it's not allowed.

Comment: Stick your new data in a new (temporary) table, and let the database do the work for you

Comment: @TimMorton can you give more details about this?

Comment: Instead of fetching all data you could only load the users you need. When using L2 cache you might be able to do this with minimal queries. See: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/second-level-cache.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, in order to match up the new list to the old list, you’re going to have to match on the city name. While this is not ideal, it’s probably the only solution available.

If your city names are unique, no problem. But if they are not unique (Springfield AK, Springfield CA, Springfield CO, Springfield GA, Springfield ID, Springfield IL, Springfield IN, etc), you’re going to need more info to match on. Also, misspellings (springfield vs springfiled) will defeat the reason you normalized the databases...

Step one, add the new info to a new table. I’ll call it newinfo...

```
newinfo
----------
first_name
last_name
city
```

So assuming that city name is unique, the next step is to add all new unique city names to `cities`.   If you have a **unique** index on `cities.name`, you can simply

```
insert ignore into cities('name') select city from newinfo
```

Otherwise you have to join the tables to find new values:

```
insert into cities ('name') 
select newinfo.city 
from newinfo 
left join cities on newinfo.city=cities.name 
where cities.name is null
```

Now that you have all the possible cities in your `cities` table, you need to insert all the new names.  Consider how you would get the information you need to insert:

```
select newinfo.first_name, new info.last_name, cities.id 
from newinfo 
inner join cities on new info.city=cities.name
```

Then when you’re satisfied that you’re getting the right data, insert it:

```
insert into users 
values('first_name','last_name','city_id') 
select newinfo.first_name, new info.last_name, cities.id 
from newinfo 
inner join cities on new info.city=cities.name
```

Now you're done with with the table newinfo and it can be deleted.